# CarouFredSel doesn't work properly with touchSwipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I use your plugin for our project but i have a problem.

The site has several carousels with pictures and item products that function as anchors. 
The anchors are disabled from swipe by default settings. I have excluded the anchors from the list. It almost works buy i have the problem with Android Chrome browser. Swipe works but anchors don't work. You can't go to the link.

Please help me to solve the problem.

HTML

```
<div class="m-slider" style="background-color: #111010;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide-1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide-1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/slider/slide-1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="mn-prev"><span></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="mn-next"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Code Initialization

```
var mainSlider = $('.m-slider ul');

mainSlider.carouFredSel({
    auto: false,
    responsive: true,
    width: "100%",
    height: 'variable',
    items: {
        height: 'variable',
        visible: 1
    },
    prev: {
        button: function() {
            return $(this).parent().parent().find('.mn-prev');
        }
    },
    next: {
        button: function() {
            return $(this).parent().parent().find('.mn-next');
        }
    },
    swipe: {
        onMouse: true,
        onTouch: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey - welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find you get better results if you read and follow the guidelines posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that I have found in [this french post](http://www.biper-studio.com/548) and it worked brilliantly for me.

Translated to english:

1. Open jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js (or any other version you have) and comment the Swipe funcion.
2. Add the code that you find in the link above just below the call of caroufredsel function in order to call directly the Swipe function in jquery.touchSwipe.js instead of calling it from caroufredsel.

That's it. Good luck!